# Redirecting wrong URL to specif URL codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

This is my current folder structure:

[image]

Description:

- My base_url is: `localhost/shoppingCart`
- My default controller is `Welcome`

I have divided my project into 2 parts: front end and back end.

For back end my standard controller is "admin/home" (admin is folder and home is the name of controller)

For front end my standard controller is "welcome" (welcome is name of controller)

Problem:

When I enter `localhost/ShoppingCart/admin` it is going to "welcome" controller but the url remains same. I should throw some error I think.

And when I enter `localhost/ShoppingCart/admin/home` it is working properly.

I tried using route to redirect `localhost/ShoppingCart/admin` to `localhost/ShoppingCart`:

```
$route['/admin'] = "welcome";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've improved formatting a bit, and made it a bit easier to read. Have a look through the [editing help guide](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect a subfolder to your main domain, you'll have to do something like this :

```
#Redirect a sub folder to root
Redirect 301 /subfolder /
```

In your case it will be :

```
redirect 301 /admin /
```

Comment: Thanx for the solution..Do I have to put in routes.php? and what is the syntax for the above u mentioned.

Comment: No, this goes in your `.htaccess` file. Here is some [Common .htaccess Rules](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489)

Comment: Its not working.. I put "Redirect 301 /admin http://localhost/ShoppingCart" into htaccess. .

Comment: Problem is when I should enter "localhost/shoppingcart/admin" it should say page not found or redirect to homepage. But it is loading my homepage i.e "localhost/shoppingcart" with the same URL..

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem is on the routes.

Also I recommend you to use a "Good" names from controllers [Naming convention Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming))

"welcome" and "home" are not two different things as back-end and Front-end are.

now about the code

I assume that your `routes.php` file contains something like

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

now, for each sub-folder in your controller's folder you must set a default controller in `routes.php` the `$route['default_controller']` is not working in sub folders.

for you, will be something like

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin/home'
```

note, remember to set only the name that you want to use, about the symbols `/` the framework is going to manage them.

which in the url will be http://localhost/ShoppingCart/admin

Comment: thanx for the suggestion regarding naming convention.If I use "$route['admin'] = 'admin/home'" it will redirect to my backend homepage that I dont want. I want "localhost/ShoppingCart/admin" to redirect to my main domain which is "localhost/ShoppingCart"

Comment: I cannot see the point to have a private area and dont access it but if you do `$route['admin'] = "welcome"` without the `/` symbol should work.

Answer (score 0):

Every subdir in `APPPATH.'controllers'` dir should have controller that is named as same as default controller in `APPPATH.'route.php'`. If you would rename admin module `Home.php` to `Welcome.php` (class inside too), you would solve this issue. This is because, when router doesn't find `Admin.php` file for first uri segment, it seeks for `admin` directory. When finds it, if there is no next segment in url, router will seek for default controller method set in `config.php` file. It's easy to solve having unified name for home or welcome page in every subdir as well as in `controllers` dir.